# How to create dialog for user input in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using `contextMenu` to run a Chrome extension on some selected text on a page.
When I click on the contextMenu, I'd like to prompt the user for some additional input.
For this purpose, it'd be ideal to popup a window. After the user filled the dialog and click `confirm` button, I'd like to recuperate the inputs.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to implement this? I've checked the `Chrome API`, couldn't find anything related.

For the popup dialog, I'd like to put it in the middle of the screen(something similar to `Vimium` help dialog)

Comment: 1) open a small window using chrome.windows.create or 2) insert the dialog in the current page as a DOM element or 3) use the built-in [prompt()](https://devdocs.io/dom/window/prompt).

Comment: @wOxxOm thx. if i create a window by option 1), can i run a content script on it and get the user inputs?

Comment: Not a content script. You'll use an html file in your extension that loads its own js file using a standard `<script src="file.js">` tag.

Comment: BTW this can be useful: [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: @wOxxOm thx again. What should be in `file.js` that can send the data back to my `background page`?

Comment: It can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).